# group first, make bucketauto second in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a dataset structured like that:

```
 {
          "id": 1230239,
          "group_name": "A",
          "confidence": 0.14333882876354542,

  },
  {
          "id": 1230240,
          "group_name": "B",
          "confidence": 0.4434535,

   },
```

Etc.

It is pretty simple to calculate buckets and number of items in each bucket of confidence level, using `$bucketauto` like that:

```
{
  "$bucketAuto": {
     "groupBy": "$confidence",
     "buckets": 4
 }
}
```

But how can I do the same for each group, separately?

I tried this one:

```
    {"$group": {
                    "_id": "group",
                    "data": {
                        "$push": {
                            "confidence": "$confidence",
                        }
                    }
                }
                },
                {
                    "$bucketAuto": {
                        "groupBy": "$data.confidence",
                        "buckets": 4
                    }
                }
```

But that does not work.

What I need roughly is this as an output:

```
{ 'groupA': 
     {
            "_id": {
                "min": 0.0005225352581638143,
                "max": 0.2905137273072962
            },
            "count": 67
        },
        {"_id": {
                "min": 0.2905137273072962,
                "max":0.5531611756507283,
            },
            "count": 43
        },
}, 
{ 'groupB': 
     {
       "_id": {
                "min": 0.0005225352581638143,
                "max": 0.2905137273072962
            },
            "count": 67
        },
        {"_id": {
                "min": 0.2905137273072962,
                "max":0.5531611756507283,
            },
            "count": 43
        },
}
```

Any advice or hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$facet` to the rescue -- the "multigroup" operator.  This pipeline:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$facet: {
  "groupA": [
{$match: {"group_name": "A"}}
,{$bucketAuto: {
        "groupBy": "$confidence",
        "buckets": 3
    }}
           ]

  ,"groupB": [
{$match: {"group_name": "B"}}
,{$bucketAuto: {
        "groupBy": "$confidence",
        "buckets": 3
    }}
           ]

    }}
   ]);
```

yields the output you seek:

```
{
    "groupA" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "min" : 0.14333882876354542,
                "max" : 0.34333882876354543
            },
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "min" : 0.34333882876354543,
                "max" : 0.5433388287635454
            },
            "count" : 2
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "min" : 0.5433388287635454,
                "max" : 0.5433388287635454
            },
            "count" : 1
        }
    ],
    "groupB" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "min" : 0.5433388287635454,
                "max" : 0.7433388287635454
    // etc. etc.
```

If you want to go totally dynamic, you'll need to do it in two passes: first get the distinct group names, then build the `$facet` expression from those names:

```
db.foo.distinct("group_name").forEach(function(name) {
        fct_stage["group" + name] = [
                                     {$match: {"group_name": name}}
                                     ,{$bucketAuto: {
                                             "groupBy": "$confidence",
                                             "buckets": 3
                                         }}
                                     ];
    });

db.foo.aggregate([ {$facet: fct_stage} ]);
```